# SVG/EMF/WMF from MS Word to PDF

Tags: svg, ms-office, converters, wmf

I have a question. I'm dutch so I asked this on dutch forums but nobody knew the answer. 
I made a diagram with Lucidchart. I can export it in:

- SVG
- PNG
- PDF
- JPEG
- VISIO
- And many more.. (but not EMF or WMF)

My goal is to have a vector diagram in my MS Word document. This is not a problem, I did this. 
The problem is that I want to convert my diagram to PDF. So the picture is in PDF also a vector image. That's the good part. But the bad part is that the letter "l" is thick. I tried a lot of things but nothing helped. So mayben you can help me out.

It doesn't matter for me if it's a WMF, EMF or SVG. I just want that it is a vector image that will be shown well in PDF. 
I need to use MS Word, because I insert de picture in my picture. I already used Inkscape, Coreldraw etc. but that didn't help.

Do you have a solution? :(

P.S. 
I use MS word 2016 (but I also have 2013 and 2010 on my other laptops)
I convert it to PDF with an online converter. I also tried to print the pdf document with Adobe but that also didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean that the letter "I" is thick? Can you post an image?  Are you saying that the text in the diagram doesn't look like the original once it has been embedded in MS Word?  Have you tried converting the text to outlines before importing?  Any vector editor should be able to do this

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft started supporting SVG since Office 2016.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2016

You can use the ribbon and insert it as any other pictures.

In the latest version of lucid and office, you can select specific objects from lucid and copy, then paste into word.

The imbedded image is an SVG.

If you left click on the image and choose "Save picture as". You can select the file type SVG to extract back the SVG file as well ( regardless if it was from copy/paste or insert picture).